# Geocoding without map

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can I to use Google maps geocode API without map?
I have a textbox with autocomplete Google Maps API Place and I want after the user has typed the street number, I get the zip code.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete is one of a small number of cases where it is permitted to use a Google Maps API service without a map, although if you do use it in conjunction with a map that map must be a Google Map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete

You don't need to use the Geocoder to extract the zipcode. It is provided in the PlaceResult object returned by a getPlaces() call on the Autocomplete object after place_changed event has occurred (ie. once a user has selected a completion):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#getting_place_information

Comment: that answers your question best :-)

Comment: HI, OK, but I must to set the zip code only after typed the street number in an other textbox, so I cannot to use place_changed event, unless I can not recall the event at any time from another textbox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you can.  Check out the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). It's simply a set of web services you can call to get a geocoding result that contains the postal code, among other things.

Comment: I cite by Google Maps Api site: "The Google Maps API provides a geocoder class for geocoding addresses dynamically from user input. These requests are rate-limited to discourage abuse of the service. If instead, you wish to geocode static, known addresses, see the Geocoding web service documentation." The Geocoding web service documentation tell: "the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited"

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize you were asking about the terms of usage. I guess you answered your own question.

Comment: As of this comment: "You can display Geocoding API results on a Google Map, or without a map. If you want to display Geocoding API results on a map, then these results must be displayed on a Google Map. It is prohibited to use Geocoding API data on a map that is not a Google map."