# Getting location coordinates from Address

Tags: ios, maps, google-geocoder

The user will be prompted enter his address in a textfield and in the backend I want to get the location coordinates of the address.

I’m using geocoding service from google but not any of their APIs. I read somewhere in their document that “use of the geocoder for any purpose other than obtaining locations that will be displayed using the google maps APIs is a violation of the Terms of Service”.

And this is how HTTP request I use

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ADDRESS_STRING&sensor=false

Can I do this? I’m confused because I'm not showing any map at all but I want to get the coordinates. Will this be violating their terms?

Comment: If you are not needing the map feature, you might consider another geocoding provider. [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/demo) provides geocoding along with address validation. Check out the [API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/address#response) and you will see that Latitude and Longitude are provided in the address response. (Disclaimer: I work for SmartyStreets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, yes, I think you'd be breaking Google's rules here. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811320/145997) answer.

You could still use iOS' built-in forward-geocoding engine. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html) for the docs.

Comment: But iOS' built-in forward-geocoding is not accurate. In fact it always shows "No result found" for Asian addresses.

Comment: Ok, then you could also have a look at MapQuest' Nominatim search API: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim. Before coding your own implementation, you can always try out a few queries and see if it works well with your use cases.

Comment: Thanks Romain. I think I should accept your since I'm leaning towards using iOS's in-built forward-geocoding. Its less accurate but less risky.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps terms are very restrictive. However, it looks like they do allow showing results without Google Maps ([Geocoding API Policies](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/policies)):

> You can display Geocoding API results on a Google Map, or without a
> map. If you want to display Geocoding API results on a map, then these
> results must be displayed on a Google Map. It is prohibited to use
> Geocoding API data on a map that is not a Google map.

So you can't display Google Geocoding API results on "non-Google" maps.

Nevertheless, please remember that you still can't cache (only lat/long on the end-use device for 30 days) and store results.

Fortunately, there are many geocoding services that are based on open data. For example, we at Geoapify allow our customers to store and even redistribute data. Try our [Geocoding API](https://www.geoapify.com/geocoding-api/), and maybe you find that it's a worthy alternative to the geocoding service from Google.

Comment: You have posted two answers within the last hour, both linking to your own company. Please review [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Comment: Three to be precise )) However, only two are related to the company. I'm an expert in the industry and can answer related questions. And, of course, it is always nice when your company provides the solution. 
I also do not see problems that I answer a few questions within 1 hour. People do that usually by having lunch or a short break, other time we are busy with other stuff.

Comment: Sure; I just wanted to make sure you are aware of the guideline.